# Bool function as class member conditions don't return a value

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

enum type{
    noboard,
    peg,
    empty
};
class board{
    public:
      //create getter 
        vector<vector<int>>getVector() const;     
      
      //create setter
      bool control_vect();
      board(vector<vector<int>> pvect);
      //display() function that prints elements of the vect data member
      void display()
      {
          for(const vector<int> &elem: vect)
          {
              for(int intElem: elem)
              {
                  if(intElem==1){
                      cout<<'P';
                  }
                  else if(intElem==0){
                      cout<<' ';
                  }
                  else if(intElem==2){
                      cout<<'.';
                  }
              }
              cout<<endl;
          }
      }

    private:
     vector<vector<int>> vect;
     
     
    
};

vector<vector<int>> board :: getVector() const 
      {
          return vect;
      }
      
board :: board(vector<vector<int>> pvect)
      {
          vect = pvect;
      }
      
bool board :: control_vect(){
       long unsigned int i,j;
    bool controller=false;
cout<<vect[0][0];
for (i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++){
    for ( j = 0; j < vect[i].size()-2; j++){
        if(vect[i][j]==1 && vect[i][j+1]==1 && vect[i][j+2]==0){
            controller=true;
            break;
        }
            
    }
    
}
    return controller;
}

    
    
  


int main()
{
    //create a board instance
   // board myBoard;
    
   
    vector<vector<int>> pvect{
    {peg,peg,peg,peg,peg},
    {noboard,peg,peg,empty,peg},
    {peg,peg,peg,peg,peg},
    };
    //cout<<pvect[0][5];
    //use the setter to set the vect data member
    board a(pvect);
    a.display();
    if(a.control_vect()==true){
        cout<<"a";
    }
    else{
        cout<<"b";
    }
    //lets print out the elements of the data member vect for the object myBoard using the display() member function
   // myBoard.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I write upside code and it run.Then I trying more complex conditions in control_vect function,The function does not give a return value.But upside least complex control_funcion return a bool value and it print vect[0][0] element.But downside do not print bool or vect[0][0].Why underside function do not return a bool value?Although similar.Also I am trying for loop and print all vector two's run.Example output:İf conditions supply print a,do not supply print b by program.

```
 bool board :: control_vect(){
    long unsigned int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++){
        for ( j = 0; j < vect[i].size(); j++){                      //Look for legal moves on the board.If there are legal moves program will continue.
            if(vect[i][j]==1 && vect[i][j+1]==1 && vect[i][j+2]==2){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
            else if(vect[i][j]==2 && vect[i][j+1]==1 && vect[i][j+2]==1){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
            else if(vect[i][j] == 1  && vect[i+1][j] == 1 && vect[i+2][j] == 2){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
            else if (vect[i][j] == 2  && vect[i+1][j] == 1 && vect[i+2][j] == 1){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
    }
    }
    return controller;
        }
```

Comment: Please format your code, create a [mcve] that clearly show what is the expected and actual output. Do you have compiler warnings enabled? Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger? The bottom function does not contain `controller` definition, so it should not compile at all.

Comment: Can you write what is the expected output of the above code and how does it differ from the actual output that you're getting right now? Also, please clarify the problem you're facing in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes that i have spotted in your given code snippet.

**Mistake 1**

You are using `using namespace std` so this will result in an **error** saying

```
error: reference to 'empty' is ambiguous
   86 |     {noboard,peg,peg,empty,peg}
```

as can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/70DqjwiP4Q2mhsTv).

**Solution to Mistake 1**
You can solve this by replacing `{noboard,peg,peg,empty,peg}` with:

```
{noboard,peg,peg,type::empty,peg} //note the type:: i have added
```

Now your program works as can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dCCTWoWO10fv8ar0).

**Mistake 2**

The 2nd code snippet that you have given does not define a `controller` variable inside the `bool board :: control_vect()` and it also does not have a `cout<<vect[0][0];`

**Solution to Mistake 2**
You can solve these by just adding the following statements inside `control_vect()`'s body:

```
 bool controller = false;
 cout << vect[0][0];
```

So the correct modified code would look like:

```
bool board :: control_vect(){
    long unsigned int i,j;
    bool controller = false; //note I HAVE ADDED THIS
    cout << vect[0][0];      //note I HAVE ADDED THIS
    for (i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++){
        for ( j = 0; j < vect[i].size(); j++){                      //Look for legal moves on the board.If there are legal moves program will continue.
            if(vect[i][j]==1 && vect[i][j+1]==1 && vect[i][j+2]==2){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
            else if(vect[i][j]==2 && vect[i][j+1]==1 && vect[i][j+2]==1){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
            else if(vect[i][j] == 1  && vect[i+1][j] == 1 && vect[i+2][j] == 2){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
            else if (vect[i][j] == 2  && vect[i+1][j] == 1 && vect[i+2][j] == 1){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
    }
    }
    return controller;
        }
```

**Mistake 3**

You were trying to access `vect[i][j+2]` and `vect[i+2][j]` but you forgot to subtract 2 from loop variable values which resulted in **Segmentation fault** as can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2CMffcx5JBKeMqPm).

```
for (i = 0; i < vect.size(); i++){//you forgot to subtract 2
        for ( j = 0; j < vect[i].size(); j++){//you forgot to subtract 2
```

**Solution to Mistake 3** You can solve this by subtracting 2 from the loop variables `i` and `j` as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < vect.size() -2; i++){ //note i have subtracted 2
        for ( j = 0; j < vect[i].size()-2; j++){//note i have subtracted 2
```

So the final correct modified code would look like:

```
bool board :: control_vect(){
    long unsigned int i,j; 
    bool controller = false;
    cout << vect[0][0];
    for (i = 0; i < vect.size() -2; i++){// note I HAVE SUBTRACTED 2
        for ( j = 0; j < vect[i].size()-2; j++){ //note I HAVE SUBTRACTED 2                   //Look for legal moves on the board.If there are legal moves program will continue.
            if(vect[i][j]==1 && vect[i][j+1]==1 && vect[i][j+2]==2){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
            else if(vect[i][j]==2 && vect[i][j+1]==1 && vect[i][j+2]==1){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
            else if(vect[i][j] == 1  && vect[i+1][j] == 1 && vect[i+2][j] == 2){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
            else if (vect[i][j] == 2  && vect[i+1][j] == 1 && vect[i+2][j] == 1){
                controller=true;
                break;
            }
    }
    }
    return controller;
        }
```

Now your 2nd code snippet for `control_vect()` works and prints `bool` and `vect[0][0]` as you want and can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pdWouMjvlhyfLuZn). The complete working program can also be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pdWouMjvlhyfLuZn).